# Creating a binary variable conditioned on values in another table in R

Tags: r, join

I'm trying to create a new flag variable (binary) for a table based on values in another table. I've looked around stackoverflow but can't seem to find a similar question.
For example, I have table A and table B, and each of them has the variable customer.

Table A:

```
A.customer
1
2
3
4
5
```

Table B:

```
B.customer
1
2
6
```

I want to create a new variable in A called flag, where if the value in customer also occurs in B, then flag=Y, else flag=N.
Like this:

```
A.customer A.flag
1          Y
2          Y
3          N
4          N
5          N
```

In what ways can I join the tables and set the new variable flag? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `%in%` operator

```
A = 1:5
B = c(1,2,6)
> A %in% B
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a new column, use `%in%` and `factor`.

```
A.flag <- TableA$A.customer %in% TableB$B.customer
TableA$A.flag <- factor(A.flag, labels = c("N", "Y"))

TableA
#  A.customer A.flag
#1          1      Y
#2          2      Y
#3          3      N
#4          4      N
#5          5      N
```

**Data.**

```
TableA <-
structure(list(A.customer = 1:5, A.flag = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")

TableB <-
structure(list(B.customer = c(1L, 2L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [**tidyverse**](https://www.tidyverse.org), you can use [`case_when`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

table_a <- data_frame(A.customer = 1:5)
table_b <- data_frame(B.customer = c(1, 2, 6))

table_a
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>   A.customer
#>        <int>
#> 1          1
#> 2          2
#> 3          3
#> 4          4
#> 5          5

table_b
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   B.customer
#>        <dbl>
#> 1          1
#> 2          2
#> 3          6

table_a %>%
  mutate(
    A.flag = case_when(
      A.customer %in% table_b$B.customer ~ "Y",
      TRUE ~ "N"
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   A.customer A.flag
#>        <int> <chr> 
#> 1          1 Y     
#> 2          2 Y     
#> 3          3 N     
#> 4          4 N     
#> 5          5 N
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

`case_when` acts like an if/else if/else. So you say "If A.customer is in `table_b$B.customer` return a value of `Y`." Then "in all other cases (the else as `TRUE` will always evaluate to TRUE) return `N`."